# Pushing to TWRP, adb shows "adb: error: connect failed: no devices/emulators found"

Tags: adb

When I try to push my rom to `/sdcard/` with TWRP, I get

```
adb push myRom.zip /sdcard/
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
adb: error: connect failed: no devices/emulators found
```

How do I resolve this error. Things seem to work with  `adb sideload` but the rom doesn't boot. The [LineageOS install instructions](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/n2awifi/install) say specifically to use with `adb push`.

Comment: It means your phone and pc cannot communicate. Do you have debugging on in your developer options? Adb and fastboot drivers on your pc? Phone specific drivers depending on make and model.

Comment: If `adb sideload` doesn't work then high probability `adb push` won't either, it's a similar process. Figure out why it wouldn't boot first?

Answer (score 1):

Try killing the process and then retrying:

```
adb kill-server
adb push myRom.zip /sdcard/
```